# What is the purpose of @ResponsePayload in the method header - spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop a web service similar to one I have already (developed by somebody else), and to do that I need to understand the purpose `@ResponsePayload` in the method header. I have something like this:

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart="get-documentList-request", namespace="http://www.foo.com/bar/ws/model/")
public @ResponsePayload DocumentListResponse getDocumentList(@RequestPayload GetDocumentListRequest documentList) throws DatatypeConfigurationException{
       //
}
```

So what does the `@ResponsePayload` in the method header do?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827895/which-way-for-restful-webservice-spring-ws-payloads-or-spring-3-mvc-rest-contro) might answer your question.

Comment: `@ResponsePayload` is SOAP equivalent of `@ResponseBody` in REST

Comment: Thank you for the input guys.

Answer (score 0):

It is the annotation for SOAP response body.
In restController, we have `@ResponseBody`, we have `@ResponsePayload` in SOAP controller(`@Endpoint`).